# Tweet from a specfic account in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, ios6, social-framework

I'm setting up twitter on iOS6 in an app.
The problem I've stumbled upon is if: the user has multiple twitter accounts how do I choose which one to share to?

I've managed to get all the accounts in an array.
But the question is how do I link this account:

```
 ACAccount *acct = [_accounts objectAtIndex:twitterAccountInt];
```

With this:

```
slComposerSheetController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
NSString *postText = [informationToBeShared objectForKey:@"postText"];
NSURL *postImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[informationToBeShared objectForKey:@"postImageURL"]];
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[informationToBeShared objectForKey:@"postURL"]];

[slComposerSheetController setInitialText:[informationToBeShared objectForKey:@"postText"]];
[slComposerSheetController addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:postImageURL]]];
[slComposerSheetController addURL:postURL];
[delegate presentViewController:slComposerSheetController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user adds more twitter accounts in settings, the operating system adds an option over the `SLComposeViewController` where the user can choose which account he wants to tweet from.

It required no changes from me.